# "Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Headers" ERROR for Axios Post Requests, AWS API Gateway (RESOLVED)

Tags: amazon-web-services, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway

API endpoints with AWS API Gateway.
Enabled CORS successfully for all resources.

GET method works.
POST method works on ThunderClient.
Post DOES NOT work on local development.

Error Message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<endpoint>' from origin 
'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header 
field in preflight response.
```

Attempted adding headers to

```
const res = await axios.post(invokeURL, studentData, {
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
                }
```

as well as in my Lambda Function

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
};
return response;
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

update:

added

```
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        }
    };
```

```
... 
 const response = await axios.post(invokeURL, studentData, config);
```

looking and chrome dev tools, there is no response headers(0).

---

## RESOLVED

in AWS API Gateway Post Method;

Method Response;

Create Response for HTTP Status 200;

Include Response Headers:

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers"

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

In Lambda Code
Include headers:

```
 const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        };
        return response;
```